# PyCharm how to get back classical Ctrl +[] indentation function back

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

How to use shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl + [</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + ]</kbd> for indentation in PyCharm?

Cause it is really difficult as suddenly it is gone from my PyCharm. Please let me know how to get it back.

I tried changing the preference for them, the documentation showed but I don't need that, I want my classic indentation shortcut back.

Answer (score 0):

I also was interested in this question.

1. Go to settings (ctrl+alt+s).
2. Find **keymap** -> "indent (or unindent) line or selection"
3. add or change existing keymap to ctrl+[ (or ctrl+])